# Remote name cannot be resolved when performing write operation in DocumentDB using .net sdk

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I suddenly got:

> "Remote name cannot be resolved
>   `https://[mydocdbaccountname]-northeurope.documents.azure.com`"

when calling either `CreateDocumentAsync()` or `ReplaceDocumentAsync()`. It was working before and just stopped working without changing anything in the code. `ReadDocumentAsync()` works fine.

I'm using the primary key to establish client connection. I tried changing that to the secondary key and regenerated the primary key but it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to a service-specific outage, and not a programming-specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the region name is not the issue or anything to do with auth keys. There is a DNS glitch in North Europe and we are working through it. Please check with the Azure advisory/support in the meantime. we are in the final step of validating the mitigation. We will post an update on @documentdb soon. thanks much.

Comment: The DNS issue in North Europe should be resolved now.